# NodeJS change MySQL column name when displaying data

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

I am creating an API using NodeJS+Express that display a bunch of data from MySQL. The real column name in MySQL is user_id, user_salary. But I don't want it to be appear on screen, so I want to change to something like (user_id -> ID, user_salary-> SAL, so in JSON format, my data it will be:

```
{"status":200,"response":"SUCCESS","data":[{"ID":"OV100","SAL":100000},{"ID":"OV1000","SAL":1000000},{"ID":"OV150","SAL":150000}]}
```

I have googling about this but no luck.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show the code where you get the data from MySQL

Comment: You can either use the `AS` SQL keyword to alias your output columns, or use `.map()` in JS to map the old objects into another shape.

Comment: @cubrr here is the code:     let sql = "select user_id, user_salary from salary";
    let q = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(results.length)
    res.end(JSON.stringify({"status": 200,  "response": 'SUCCESS', "data": results}));

Comment: Ahhh your idea about use AS in mysql is great! Why I didn't think about make an alias in my query....thanks a lot @cubrr, God Bless You

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer so you can resolve the question :)

Comment: Marked as answered. Many thanks @cubrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do this in SQL, in JS over at your backend, or even in your frontend.

### Do it in SQL

Use `AS`.

```
const sql = 'select user_id as "ID", user_salary as "SAL" from salary';
```

### Do it in JS

Use `Array.map`.

```
conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(results.length)
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
          "status": 200, 
          "response": 'SUCCESS',
          "data": results.map(({ user_id, user_salary }) => ({
            ID: user_id,
            SAL: user_salary
          }))
        }));
})
```

Comment: The latter one I was looking for and it works perfectly, thank you!